# KeyCode Value for Alt is showing up as Shift

Tags: c#, vb.net, keypress

I have a snippet of code I am using:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Alt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You pressed the Alt key.");
        }
```

So as you can see, from this snippet of code I just want to tell is the Alt key is pressed, and when it is the message box will appear.

But what is happening is when I run the program, and I press the Alt key the value of `e.KeyCode` is `ShiftKey`.

So my question is, why is the value not AltKey?

Comment: which event you get the key input? try with `if (e.Alt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You pressed the Alt key.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to detect Alt key press you can do as below

```
if (e.Alt)
{
   MessageBox.Show("You pressed the Alt key.");
}
```

check [KeyEventArgs.Alt Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.alt.aspx)

e.Modifiers will help you to find key combinations like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd>

for that example your key will be <kbd>T</kbd>, and modifiers will be <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>